# Which words to use to characterize a person who likes to understand things deeply?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

I want to use this phrase in my CV:

> person who always tries to understand the very essence of processes and things.

The idea is to show that I like to understand things deeply.

My concern is that my phrase sounds awkward.

What other phrases can you suggest?

---

upd.
"Analytical" conveys the meaning but it is one word, while I would like to express it in phrase.

Frankly speaking "deep thinker" and "a thoughtful person" sounds cliche.

Apparently this question is not easy and couldn't be solved by using thesaurus.
The only suitable variant that I found in thesaurus is "curious", however I already used this word previously and do not want to tautologize.

Comment: Perhaps *enthusiastic* or *inquisitive* will do!

Comment: "Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic." It's honestly not too easy too look this up in a thesaurus if you don't have good keywords to begin with -- must asking a question really be so hard on this site?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of person might be called ***deep thinker*** or ***a thoughtful person.***

Answer (score 0):

> **an *analytical* person/mind**

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.se/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/analytical) defines *analytical* as follows:

> **analytical:** examining or liking to examine things very carefully:
>
> - *He has a very analytical mind.*
> - *Some students have a more analytical approach to learning.*

[Wikipedia on **analysis**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis):

> Analysis is the process of breaking a complex topic or substance into smaller parts in order to gain a better understanding of it.

In many cases it involves getting to the core, the essence of things, so I think it’s pretty close to what you want to express.

Moreover, it’s a common word that won’t stand out as confusing or out-of-context in a CV.